# handle SIGINT with scanf in loop

Tags: c, signals, scanf, sigint

I have to take input from user in a while loop and then take some action. And I also want to exit my code on ctrl+c input.

```
void my_signal_handler(int sig)
{
    running = false;
    signal(sig, SIG_IGN);
}
int main(void)
{
    struct sigaction sa = {{0}};
    sa.sa_handler = &my_signal_handler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = 0;

    if (sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "sigaction error\n");
        return -1;
    }
    while(running)
    {
        printf("enter number: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        // take action based on  number
    }
}
```

Problem with this code is after pressing ctrl+c, it doesn't exit but it waits for input for scanf. So once I press an extra key, the program exits (signal handler gets called).

How can I remove this extra step of giving input to scanf after pressing ctrl+c ?

Comment: Could you improve your question by motivating it (so please **edit your question**), please?

Comment: BTW, the given code does not compile. There is a missing double-quotes in `scanf(%d", &num);`

Answer (score 3):

You should install the signal handler. At the very least, add

```
signal(SIGINT, my_signal_handler);
```

inside your `main` *before* the `while(running)`, but better use [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html).

You should also know that *stdio* is [buffering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer); usually `stdout` is line-buffered when it is a terminal (but see [setvbuf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html) and friends). So you should either call [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) (probably as `fflush(NULL);`) before the `scanf` inside the loop, or terminate every `printf` format control string with an *explicit* `\n`.

At last, [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) can fail and is returning the count of scanned items, which you should test.

BTW, your  `main` is wrong, should be defined as `int main(void)` or preferably `int main(int argc, char**argv)`.

However (assuming you are on Linux), read very carefully [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) (notice what is said about signal handlers and async-signal safe functions) and POSIX [`signal.h` documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/signal.h.html) and declare your `running` flag as

```
volatile sigatomic_t running;
```

(or perhaps, in C11, as `volatile _Atomic bool running;`)

The [`volatile` qualifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_(computer_programming)) is very important. Otherwise, the compiler is allowed to optimize (and e.g. pretend that `running` is *always* true).

Notice that using [signal(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) is often a bad idea. First, if you really need signal handling, you'll better use [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html). Then your call to  `signal(sig, SIG_IGN);` is, in your case, useless (since the `running` volatile flag would have been changed in the signal handler). At last, for multiplexing input (& output), you could use [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) which can be used to wait and test if there is some available input on `stdin` (actually `STDIN_FILENO` which is 0), and more generally to implement [event loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop). You could use (instead of `poll` which I strongly recommend) the old and nearly obsolete [select(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html), but you'll rather use [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html). See also [epoll(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html) & [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) but you probably don't need them.

Be aware that in terminals, `stdin` is often a tty (check that with [isatty(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html)) following the [line discipline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_discipline) (so some of the line buffering happens *inside* the kernel). Read the [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) page. Consider using the [GNU readline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline) library and function (or perhaps [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/)), which might be what you really need.

Read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and take the habit of reading the documentation of every function that you are using.

Comment: Actually in the line //signal handler configuration, I have added proper code for sigaction. I will update the code again to show my actual_code.

Comment: @BS Can you show a code example of this line "multiplexing input (& output), you could use poll(2) which can be used to wait and test if there is some available input on stdin (actually STDIN_FILENO which is 0)."

Comment: That might take too much time on my side (especially if you are not very familiar with Linux programming). I gave references, notably the ALP book